$\epsilon$-secure encryption system
Suppose the message space of a symmetric key encryption system is infinite (countable) with a probability distribution on it such that { $m \in M: Pr(m) \neq 0$ } is infinite. For a real number $\epsilon \in [0, 1)$ we say that $(Gen, Enc, Dec)$ is $\epsilon-secure$ if and only if for every $m \in M$ with $Pr(m) \neq 0$ and every $c \in C$ we have $|\frac{Pr(m)-Pr(m|c)}{Pr(m)}| \leq \epsilon$
Suppose the key space and the cipher text space are countable with a probability distributions on them. For which $\epsilon$'s there exists an $\epsilon$-secure system on $M$?
(Encryption system not necessarily deterministic.)
